# Load error for core_ext time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install a gem for my Rails 3.2.14 app.
When I run bundle it installs fine but when I try to run the server I get:

```
/Users/maccer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/time (LoadError)
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by permissions on your gems folder.

First check permissions on `/Users/maccer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems`.

After that try :

```
chmod -R 755 /Users/maccer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems
```